# Регулярное выражение, которое берет предпоследнее слово из строки (слова разделены пробелами)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как будет выглядеть регулярное выражение, которое берет предпоследнее слово из строки. Слова в строке разделены пробелами.

Comment: Можно (и нужно) без регулярного выражения. Например в Python это будет выглядеть вот так: `s.split(' ')[-2]`

Comment: как показал ответ @InDevX можно и одной регуляркой обойтись  **\w+(?=\s+\w+\W*$)**

Comment: регулярка медленее и ее сложнее понять

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, на **php**, к примеру, вот так можно:

`explode(" ", $str)[str_word_count($str)-2]`

А регуляркой как-то так:

`\w+(?=\s+\w+$)`

[regex101(dot)com](https://regex101.com/r/igjCuo/63)

regex + php:

```
preg_match('~\w+(?=\s+\w+$)~',"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

UPD: с комментария [@rvs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/13468/rvs), на **python**:

```
s.split(' ')[-2]
```

Comment: благодарю - \w+(?=\s+\w+$) хорошо срабатывает.

Comment: Учтите, что, к примеру, стоит поставить пробел в конце и всё ломается с данной регуляркой. Лучше всё-таки использовать возможности языка и обойтись без неё

Comment: Если в конце предполагается наличие пробелов, то регулярку можно будет записать так: \w+(?=\s+\w+\s*$)

Comment: @AndreyZinovich Я захочу минус поставить - тоже регулярку править?

Comment: нет, если предполагается наличие еще и других метасимволов в конце, то можно более универсальное выражение использовать: \w+(?=\s+\w+\W*$)